# A dense orbit of the logistic map

Tags: sequences-and-series

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27573/rational-numbers-with-dense-orbits-in-0-1-under-iteration-by-fx-4x1-x) question, it was determined in the answers that the logistic map $x_n: [0,1] \mapsto [0,1]$ defined by $x_{n+1} = 4x_n(1-x_n)$ has a dense orbit if and only if every finite binary string appears in the binary expansion of the point $x_0$. My question is, what is the equivalent condition for the sequence to be dense around the point $\dfrac{1}{2}$? In other words, for any arbitrarily small positive $\epsilon$, there exists an $n$ such that $|x_n-1/2| < \epsilon$.

For example, if $x_0 = \dfrac{1}{26}$ would it satisfy this property?

Answer (score 2):

Logistic map is semi-conjugate to the shift. If $F(t)=-(1/2)\cos 2\pi t+1/2$
then $F(2t)=f\circ F(t)$ where $f$ is your logistic map. To the point $1/2$
correspond $t_1=1/4$ and $t_2=3/4$, and $t\mapsto 2t$ just cuts the first digit
of the dyadic expansion. Therefore, if you want your orbit of $T_0$ to visit every neighborhood of $t_1$ or $t_2$ infinitely many times, it is necessary and sufficient that the dyadic expansion of $t$ contains sequences $001000000...$
or $011000000...$ with arbitrary many zeros in the tail.

Comment: In the case of $x_0 = \dfrac{1}{26}$ would its orbit be dense around the point $1/2$?

Comment: I do not know the digits of $(\arccos(12/13))/(2\pi)$.